# Regex search pattern excluding one file

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2010

in Visial Studio 2010 I want to use a regex pattern in the built-in Find and Replace Dialog, and I want to search in that type of files `*.cshtml, *.cs, *.js` but except e.g. `myController.cs` file. How to do it ?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
\b^(?!myController\.cs).+\.(cs(html)?|js)$\b
```